# C scanf() function Bug?

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I am having a very hard time figuring why this is happening. When I compile and run my code on the linux terminal, the `scanf()` function appears to work well in the sense that it accepts input, however for some reason it doesn't actually store that value into the designated variable, instead it makes it 1.
I have looked over my code and can't see and issue, but I do lack knowledge in C, so any help is appreciated.

```
int main() {

    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    printf("Please enter the value of a: ");
    a = scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);

    printf("Please enter the value of b: ");
    b = scanf("%d", &e);
    printf("b = %d\n", b);

    printf("Please enter the value of c: ");
    c = scanf("%d", &e);

    printf("C = %d\n", c);
    c = c + b;
    printf("C = %d\n", c);

    if (a > 1) {
        printf("B = %d\n", b);
        printf("C = %d\n", c);
    } else {
        printf("A is smaller or equal to 1 \n");
    }

    if (b > 3 || c > 3) {
        printf("A = %d\n", a);
    } else {
        printf("B is less than or equal to 3\n");
        printf("B = %d\n", b);
        printf("C = %d\n", c);
    }
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion here is stemming from what variable stores the value scanned in, and what is being returned from `scanf()`.

- The second argument passed to `scanf()` is the address where the scanned value will be stored
- The return value from `scanf()` is the number of values scanned (or one of a few error codes)

With this understanding, take another look at this code:

```
int a,b,c,d,e,f;
printf("PLease enter the value of a: ");
a = scanf("%d", &d);
printf("a = %d\n",a);
```

The third line scans a value and stores it in the variable `d` (hence the `&d` at the end of the `scanf()` call). It also stores the *number of values scanned* into the variable `a`. Then, it prints out `a` – which, at this point, is 1, since the previous `scanf()` call only found one value.

A better pattern would be to scan into the variable you're asking about (so, in this case, passing `&a` to `scanf()`), then checking the return value for any errors that occurred before proceeding in your program.

Comment: So do you mean just get rid of the &d so that the code looks like this:  scanf("%d", &a);   printf("a = %d\n",a);?  if so then how do I get rid of this error : example3.c:6:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   scanf("%d", &a);
  As that is what I had done in the first place

Comment: Also, thank you for your contribution, I know at least know why the value is always one as I only input 1 value.

Comment: That change would work to get the typed value into the variable `a`. The warning is telling you that you're not checking how many values are scanned; for example, `scanf()` might return 0 if you scan an integer but type in "asdf." You could do something like `int scanned = scanf("%d", &a); if (scanned < 1) return -1;` to quit your program early if `scanf()` is unsuccessful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have rather limited knowledge in Objective C and have come from java but that was well explained, it now works :)